# python csv reader delete special character in uuid

Tags: python, csv, uuid

Got a large csv file like

```
fab47e7c-05df-4315-b23f-de2cfc8b180f,Lindie,Lilybelle,Lindie.Lilybelle@yopmail.coma
959d21f-e131-473c-ae44-cfea24dbaf3f,Vere,Ax,Vere.Ax@yopmail.com
dd20bea2-f3a8-4283-82e2-501efb846fa8,Lacie,Byrne,Lacie.Byrne@yopmail.com
```

and some of uuids imported with typo like

```
#@3b751941-dca2-4224-b453-d81c53cc4c6e%$,Ivett,Urias,Ivett.Urias@yopmail.com
```

im trying to replace that symbols in uuid but not really understand  how to do it right.

my code is like

```
def read_csv(path, string):
    with open(path, 'r') as data:
        reader = csv.DictReader(data)
        for row in reader:
            string.match(row['id'])
```

where the string is a regex for uuid

```
string = re.compile('[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$', re.I)
```

Comment: > "where the string is a regex for uuid"

how does it look?

Comment: string = re.compile('[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$', re.I)

Comment: > string = re.compile('[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}$', re.I)

this won't find example id with typo

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong, it's looking for regexes that don't have any characters after them, because of the "$" symbol at the end. Use this:

`[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}`

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/TJXCaR/1